# PowerShell understanding - Function Do If exit

Tags: powershell

I've been tasked with automation at my workplace and need to get my theory understanding up to scratch so I can start learning and scripting.

I have a simple function I have created below, that prompts the user to enter a country. When the country is entered incorrectly 3 times, the program should exit.

I have 2 theory/scripting understanding problems

1. The write output in incorrect country text should display a countdown 3-2-1, then quit.
2. The `do..while` doesn't work. I am hypothesizing I am doing something wrong here.

May I please have assistance understanding where I am going wrong. I'm not asking for coding help but even theory pointers. I rarely ask for help and would like to pay it back somehow if possible.

```
$count = 0

function game {
    do {
        $country = Read-Host "What is the best country in the world? "

        if ($country -eq "Australia") {
            $(win)
        } else {
            $count++
            Write-Host "Wrong answer you have $count attempts remaining."
            Write-Host "Try again:"
            $(game)
        }
    } while ($count -le 3)
}

function win {
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "You Win"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are counting the attempts backwards you should start with making count 3, and decrement instead of increment, also calling `game` after else, is not just asking the question again, is creating recursion, If you want to use recursion, you do not need a loop, here is an example with a while loop, and using echo(I prefer the *nix ways).

```
$count = 3

function game {
    while  ($count -gt 0){
        $count--
        $country = Read-Host "What is the best country in the world? "
        if ($country -eq "Any") {
            $(win)
            break # stop the loop, we have correct answer
        } else {
            echo "Wrong answer you have $count attempts remaining"
            if ($count -ne 0){ echo "Try again: "}
        }
    }
}

function win {
    clear-host
    Write-host "You Win"
}
game # remember to call the first function to start the script
```

Example output of failing 3 times:

```
> .\3-times.ps1
What is the best country in the world? : a
Wrong answer you have 2 attempts remaining
Try again:
What is the best country in the world? : b
Wrong answer you have 1 attempts remaining
Try again:
What is the best country in the world? : c
Wrong answer you have 0 attempts remaining
```

Edit:

Here is an example of how it would look in a recursive way without loops.

```
function game {
    Param ([int]$max_attempts)
    if ($max_attempts -eq 0 ) # check we still have attempts
    { 
        Write-Output "You lost"
        return
    } else {
        Write-Output "You have $max_attempts attempts remaining"
        $country = Read-Host "What is the best country in the world? "
        if ($country -eq "Any") {
            $(win)
        } else {
            Write-Output "Wrong answer"
            $max_attempts-- # one attempt spent
            game($max_attempts)
        }
    }
}
function win {
    clear-host
    Write-host "You Win"
}
game(3) # start script
```

Output:

```
> .\3-times-recursive.ps1
You have 3 attempts remaining
What is the best country in the world? : a
Wrong answer
You have 2 attempts remaining
What is the best country in the world? : b
Wrong answer
You have 1 attempts remaining
What is the best country in the world? : c
Wrong answer
You lost
```

Comment: Hi Mate thanks for the answer. A question I have is, which is better for a script like this, the Top loop style, or your parameter style, also, I noticed the loop way used a break whereas the parameter style used Return, is each suited for each script differently?

Comment: For me it would be which ever I understand the most, and the one that makes the code more readable, the recursion (parameter) style is sometimes the shortest way to approach a problem, but your code can get harder to read. I recommend you to use the one you understand the most.